# JNI file doesn’t recognize vector<Mat>

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, java-native-interface

I am trying to access a pixel in Mat inside of a vector using Open Cv, this way :

```
vector<Mat> digitsVect(9);
digitsVect[k].at<int>(i,j)
```

it works fine in visual studio  - C++
but doesn’t work in JNI file in Eclipse. 
i get the error:

> symbol `at` could not be resolved.
>   Method `at` could not be resolved.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: What's the declaration of `Mat`?

Comment: As it's tagged OpenCV, it will be their cv::Mat class. However I think more details are needed...

Comment: cv::mat wont be included by default in you JNI libs, are you sure you have handled library linking properly ? By what I remember I had to install a set of libs for OpenCV on my device

Comment: the Mat is : cv::Mat. 
the way we pushed Mat into the vector is :
digitsVect.push_back( Mat(28,28,CV_32SC1,Scalar(0))) ;
we did install all the OpenCV libs ( other opencv functions are working on Mats that are not part of a Vector)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just ignoring the errors and building the project? Sometimes Eclipse does not recognize headers or symbols properly, especially with the Android developer tools. If you get compiler errors from building, they should be more specific and easier to debug.

If Eclipse is preventing you from building the project due to the perceived errors, you can turn off Eclipse's error-checking by going to Window > Preferences and editing the C++ code analysis settings.

Comment: Tried that , didnt work, can run the code becuse of the error.